# I have to manually start bash

Tags: linux, bash, vpn

I'm somewhat a Linux noob, so I'm sorry if this is a very basic question. I tried to look on superuser for other answers, but i'm not exactly sure what i'm looking for.

So, here's my problem. When I log in to my vpn server, it no longer opens bash automatically. Instead it just gives me the

```
$
```

instead of

```
$ user@host / location
```

When I log in with my root user, it actually loads bash on login. I can load bash manually with the

```
/bin/bash
```

command, but I rather understand what happened, that changed this in the first place, and how to restore it.

Comment: How do you know you are not running bash? Bash could be set up up to just show $ to you. You can you 'echo $0' to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this command:

```
grep $USER /etc/passwd
```

<sup>([Explained here](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+%24USER+%2Fetc%2Fpasswd). Alternatively use `cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER`, both are equivalent but the latter one may be easier to understand. It's less efficient, though, so it's not recommended for scripts etc. Thanks to @Mat for this suggestion.)</sup>

It will return your user account's information. Here's mine:

```
gronostaj:x:1000:1000:gronostaj,,,:/home/gronostaj:/bin/bash
```

The part after the last colon (`/bin/bash`) is my default shell. It seems that yours is `sh`. That would mean that you either have it explicitly set as your default shell (`/bin/sh`) or you have no default shell/invalid one, so Linux falls back to `sh` which is the most basic one.

**To switch to `bash`**, run this command:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

It will ask for your password and change default shell to `bash`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. However, I must have broke something. This is my account info: "david:x:1000:100::/home/david:" And when I try to switch bash, i get this "You may not change the shell for 'david'."

Comment: I tried to change it with root, and that worked however. Thank you very much for pointing me to chsh.

Comment: Note to @Mat: I am aware that `grep` can read files, but I have intentionally used `cat` and pipe. This is a simple one-time command, so performance is not an issue. `cat | grep` is more explicit than `grep` alone, so it's often easier to understand for beginners. And I don't have to remember order of arguments for `grep` ;)

Comment: I understand what you say but completely disagree. Especially if you're show stuff to beginners - teach the right way. It's less typing and more efficient. If you start by teaching bad habits, well, they stick. (But indeed this is a minor nit. Have it your way :-) ).

Comment: @Mat if you find if truly offensive, you can always edit the answer, especially if you think it will contribute something positive to said answer. :-)

Comment: A more general way would be 'getent passwd user'. Users wont always come from /etc/passwd.

Comment: @Mat As a devoted pythonist I believe that [*explicit is better than implicit* and *readability counts*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), but majority seems to agree with your reasoning so I've edited the answer. (Also, *In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess*... `grep` arguments order ;) )